# How to map a domain

Tags: domain, web, mapping

Just wondering if anyone can assist me with the following query.

I want to allow a customer to utilise our web application for their clients and they have a spare domain.

How do we go about mapping their domain to point to our application and then their clients will think the application is theirs and not us as it sits on our domain?

Comment: Hey Bill - you really should go back and mark answers to your previous questions as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

Have there domain DNS A record point to your web application IP.  If you use Virtual Hosts, make sure you add a record for that domain.  Also depending on your application it may need modification to "think" its your customers application.

Comment: Hi, I have a hosted web server for which the application sits on. What record would I need to add? thanks

Comment: Who ever owns the domain needs to make DNS changes on the listed name servers for the said domain.